# gitlab: can merge files auto-generated by merge-request tests?

Tags: gitlab

When a merge request happens, I'd like to run a script that not only runs tests on the committed sources, but also subsequently commit some files some files that are updated as part of the regression. These might be things like references and checksums of expensive-to-build assets who's build depends on the checked-in code (which are too expensive to expect the developer to pre-build and better handled through a clustered compute environment).

I've heard this is problematic for gitlab (for example, it the developer commits more files to this branch while the tests are running, they may be merged untested). Is this true?